# Using PointCut expression inside xml files with multiple combination

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

The project that I have been assigned to uses xml files to create aop configs.

Part1:

The aop configured in my xml file is:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(public * com.RR..manager..*.*(..)) &amp;&amp; 
            !execution(public * com.RR.DD.manager.IMan.isNonProductionEnvironment(..)) &amp;&amp; 
            !execution(public * com.RR.DD.manager.IMan.isProductionEnvironment(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(public * com.highradius..manager..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(public * com.scraper.correspondence..manager..*.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

Can someone explain what is being done here in there. I have an idea about what point cut does but here I cant figure out what those "&amp" means and the entire stuff altogether is perplexing me.

Part2:

Also the reason i am exploring this is because I am getting "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress" exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3466) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144) ~[spring-orm-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95) ~[spring-orm-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:936) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:748) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.isTriggerEmailForNonProdEnvironment(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.scraper.EmailManagement.filterEmailAddress(EmailManagement.java:525) ~[agent_base-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at com.scraper.EmailManagement.sendMailWithTemplateAndCc(EmailManagement.java:637) ~[agent_base-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at com.highradius.eci.agentframework.executor.impl.ECIStandardJobExecutor.sendJobStatusMailNotifiation(ECIStandardJobExecutor.java:823) ~[eci_framework-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at com.highradius.eci.agentframework.executor.impl.ECIStandardJobExecutor.executeJob(ECIStandardJobExecutor.java:458) ~[eci_framework-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at com.highradius.eci.agentframework.ECIStandardAction.run(ECIStandardAction.java:89) ~[eci_framework-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at com.scraper.ScheduledAgentLauncher.immediatelyLaunchScheduledAgent(ScheduledAgentLauncher.java:365) ~[agent_base-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at com.scraper.WrapperAgentAction.run(WrapperAgentAction.java:182) ~[agent_base-18.6.0-SNAPSHOT-falconfit.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3068.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:265) ~[spring-core-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:257) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.2.3.jar:?]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.2.3.jar:?]
```

The line in the exception "at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.isTriggerEmailForNonProdEnvironment(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]" is about the function "isTriggerEmailForNonProdEnvironment" being declared at Iman interface and defined by ImanImpl class.

Help for any of the part would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for part 1:**

Xml editors don't understand '&' operator so to make XMl editor understand we use `&amp;` in your case `&amp;&amp;` means '&&' .

**Solution for part 2:**
Please add below code in xml so that when you use @Transactional annotation,It can refer to this.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEntitymangrfctry" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```